# foreach send mail body

Tags: php, email

I used a form "addrow" and "deleterow":

```
function addRow(tableID) {
    var table = document.getElementById(tableID);
    var rowCount = table.rows.length;
    if(rowCount < 5){                           // limit the user from creating fields more than your limits
        var row = table.insertRow(rowCount);
        var colCount = table.rows[0].cells.length;
        for(var i=0; i<colCount; i++) {
            var newcell = row.insertCell(i);
            newcell.innerHTML = table.rows[0].cells[i].innerHTML;
        }
    }else{
         alert("Maximum Passenger per ticket is 5.");

    }
}
```

But `send.php` cant send email, gives me this error:

> PHP Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '.' in /home/metroloj/public_html/form/dene1/send.php on line 52

on this line:

```
<?php foreach($BX_NAME as $a => $b){ ?>
```

I cant add send php this code part:

```
<?php foreach($BX_NAME as $a => $b){ ?>
    <tr>
    <p>
        <td>
            <?php echo $a+1; ?>
        </td>
        <td>
            <label>Name</label>
            <input type="text" readonly="readonly" name="BX_NAME[$a]" value="<?php echo $BX_NAME[$a]; ?>">
        </td>

    </p>
    </tr>
<?php } ?>
```

```php
<?php foreach($BX_NAME as $a => $b){ ?>

<input type="text" readonly="readonly" name="BX_NAME[$a]" value="<?php echo $BX_NAME[$a]; ?>">

$mail->Body .= '<input type="text" readonly="readonly" name="BX_NAME[$a]" value="'. strip_tags($_POST['BX_NAME[$a]']) .'">';
```

Comment: Are you using [PHPMailer](https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer)?

Answer (score 0):

There may be other issues here, but I'll just address the general PHP syntax.
Opening and closing PHP tags must be used for mixed content (HTML and PHP together).

> Everything outside of a pair of opening and closing tags is ignored by the PHP parser which allows PHP files to have mixed content. This allows PHP to be embedded in HTML documents, for example to create templates.
>
> This works as expected, because when the PHP interpreter hits the `?>` closing tags, it simply starts outputting whatever it finds... until it hits another opening tag...

See [Escaping from HTML](http://php.net/manual/en/language.basic-syntax.phpmode.php).

Also, in your `foreach` examples, `$BX_NAME[$a]` has the same value as `$b`.

> foreach (array_expression as $key => $value)

So `array_expression[$key]` is the same as `$value`.

---

For example:

```php
<?php
foreach ($BX_NAME as $a => $b) {
    ?><tr>
        <td><?=$a+1?></td>
        <td>
            <label>Name</label>
            <input type="text" readonly="readonly" name="<?=$b?>" value="<?=$b?>">
        </td>
    </tr><?php
}
```

When building a string, use `.` to concatenate:

```php
foreach ($BX_NAME as $a => $b){

    ?><input type="text" readonly="readonly" name="<?=$b?>" value="<?=$b?>"><?php
    $mail->Body .= '<input type="text" readonly="readonly" name="'.$b.'" value="'.strip_tags($_POST[$b]).'">';

}
```